# Passing model from view to controller doesn't pass a model ID field

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model, controller

In my view I have a form with few fields. For model ID I have

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)
```

The model is passing to controller with ajax

```
function submitDocument() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Documents/Save_Document",
        type: "post",
        data: JSON.stringify($("#form").serialize()),
        success: function (data) {
            // ... some code goes here

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

The controller looks like

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Save_Document(DocumentModel doc)
{
    //  ... some code goes here

    return (some json result);
}
```

When I check through browser there is post values passed by the view (the whole model is populated). In the controller I don't have ID of model (ID is always zero although the ID field is successfully posted through Ajax). Why the controller loose the ID model value?

DocumentModel is described as

```
 public class DocumentModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; } // does not work

    public int id_folder { get; set; } // it works

    public string document_number { get; set; } // it works

    public System.DateTime document_date { get; set; } // it works

    public string supplier_name { get; set; } // it works

    public int id_employer { get; set; } // it works

    public bool isChecked { get; set; } // this is dummy field. maybe it makes problem?

}
```

Comment: Can you provide your "DocumentModel" class code?

Comment: I have added the DocumentModel class...

Comment: Can you provide your view code?

Comment: You might want to remove the call to "JSON.stringify", and just use this: $("#form").serialize()

Comment: @JakeBraun It works! Thank you!